# Hive not fully honoring fs.default.name/fs.defaultFS value in core-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have the NameNode service installed on a machine called `hadoop`.

The `core-site.xml` file has the `fs.defaultFS` (equivalent to `fs.default.name`) set to the following:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop:8020</value>
</property>
```

I have a very simple table called `test_table` that currently exists in the Hive server on the HDFS. That is, it is stored under `/user/hive/warehouse/test_table`. It was created using a very simple command in Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (record_id INT);
```

If I attempt to load data into the table locally (that is, using `LOAD DATA LOCAL`), everything proceeds as expected. However, if the data is stored on the HDFS and I want to load from there, an issue occurs.

I run a very simple query to attempt this load:

```
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/haduser/test_table.csv' INTO TABLE test_table;
```

Doing so leads to the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10028]: Line 1:17 Path is not legal ''/user/haduser/test_table.csv'':
Move from: hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/haduser/test_table.csv to: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_table is not valid.
Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.
```

As the error states, it is attempting to move from `hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/haduser/test_table.csv` to `hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_table`. The first path is correct because it references `hadoop:8020`; the second path is incorrect, because it references `localhost:8020`.

The `core-site.xml` file clearly states to use `hdfs://hadoop:8020`. The `hive.metastore.warehouse` value in `hive-site.xml` correctly points to `/user/hive/warehouse`. Thus, I doubt this error message has any true value.

How can I get the Hive server to use the correct NameNode address when creating tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the Hive metastore tracks the location of each table. You can see the that location be running the following in the Hive console.

```
hive> DESCRIBE EXTENDED test_table;
```

Thus, this issue occurs if the NameNode in `core-site.xml` was changed while the metastore service was still running. Therefore, to resolve this issue the service should be restarted on that machine:

```
$ sudo service hive-metastore restart
```

Then, the metastore will use the new `fs.defaultFS` for newly created tables such.

## Already Existing Tables

The location for tables that already exist can be corrected by running the following set of commands. These were obtained from Cloudera [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2_6.html) to configure the Hive metastore to use High-Availability.

```
$ /usr/lib/hive/bin/metatool -listFSRoot
...
Listing FS Roots..
hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse
hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test.db
```

Correcting the NameNode location:

```
$ /usr/lib/hive/bin/metatool -updateLocation hdfs://hadoop:8020 hdfs://localhost:8020
```

Now the listed NameNode is correct.

```
$ /usr/lib/hive/bin/metatool -listFSRoot
...
Listing FS Roots..
hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/hive/warehouse
hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test.db
```