# default.fs.name and hive.metastore.warehouse.dir do not conflict

Tags: hadoop, apache-hive

Hi When I try to run the below command

```
Load data Inpath '/data' into Table Tablename;
```

in hive shell it throws following error

```
Move from: hdfs://hadoopcluster/data to: file:/user/hive/warehouse/Tablename is not valid. Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.
```

where my default.fs.name property is

```
<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://hadoopcluster</value>
 </property>
```

where my hive.metastore.warehouse.dir is

```
 <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>
```

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Can You check the Link, if you have not applied the same mention in [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431074/hive-not-fully-honoring-fs-default-name-fs-defaultfs-value-in-core-site-xml), Its says after restarting the Metastore Service the same working properly along with Alter Nate option, which helps to rectify/update the hdfs location properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using "local" storage location /user/hive/warehouse for your Hive metastore that conflicts with the defaultFS (per Hive).

Do you mean to be using "local" storage, or HDFS?

To use HDFS for the Hive metastore setting you need to specify the full HDFS URI for that storage:

```
hdfs://hadoopcluster/user/hive/warehouse
```